# How can i read 1,A,5,B with scanner and put it while reading in a string and an int vector in Java?

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

So, i have this input at once:
1,A,5,B,10,A,8,A,17,B,17

I have these 2 lists:

```
String[] bidderName = new String[100];
int[] bidValue = new int[100];
```

I want, as i read this at once, to be able to store the numbers(1,5,10 etc.) in the bidValue list, and the names(A,B, etc.) in the biddername list.

How can i do this using java.util.Scanner, or anything else?

Than you in advance. Respects!

Comment: Any efforts put in till now ?

Comment: Yes. My main problem is that i cannot make the read stop.

Comment: please post your code and let people correct it for you.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the incovenience, it is the first time i am asking questions like this.

Comment: Thats ok, you can edit your question and post your code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the letters are the bidder names,
and that your input starts with a bidder name.

```
public class Test055 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "A,5,B,10,A,8,A,17,B,17,B,1";
        String[] bidderName = new String[100];
        int[] bidValue = new int[100];

        String[] data = input.trim().split(",");
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
            bidderName[i/2] = data[i];
            bidValue[i/2] = Integer.parseInt(data[i + 1]);
            k++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println(bidderName[i] + " // " + bidValue[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The input starts with a number. The first number represents the starting bid. But this code worked perfectly for me! Thank you very much, i will modify it accordingly to my needs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Scanner, but I wouldn't. The input is short enough (unless you have thousands of these) to read it in once and use Java regular expressions:

```
String s = "1,A,5,B,10,A,8,A,17,B,17";
String[] split = s.split(",");
for (String current : split) {
    if (current.matches("^\\d+$")) {
        System.out.println("handle number " + current);
    } else
        System.out.println("handle letter " + current);
}
```

Consider using an ArrayList rather than an array so you don't have to know the number of elements in each "array" up front.

Answer (score 0):

First try to do it by yourself

Split the string using ',' use `split(",")`  then you will get string array which contains both letters and numbers
if you are sure that sequence follows same pattern add every odd index tokens to int array `using Integer.parseInt()`
put even indexes directly to your array

Comment: I did, otherwise i would not search for this. I am having a contest tomorrow, and it's the first time i am coding in Java at a contest. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify where the input is coming from, but for example, if it's coming from System.in, you could do something like this:

```
String[] bidderName = new String[100];
int[] bidValue = new int[100];
int bvIndex = 0;
int bnIndex = 0;    

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
   if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
       bidderValue[bvIndex++] = scanner.nextInt();
   else {
       bidderName[bnIndex++] = scanner.next();
   }
}
```

You would want some sort of terminal condition in addition to scanner.hasNext(), but that's up to you to determine.

Comment: Yes, yes, i managed to make it work. Than you very much my virtual coding friend! Have a nice day!